# How to exclude Java file when using Sonar scanner

Tags: flutter, sonarqube

I want to analyze my Flutter code and using SonarQube. I am getting error when using Sonar scanner, I have added `sonar.exclusions=**/*.java` in file, but still it is showing.

Error log

> ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
> org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Your project contains .java files,
> please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property, or
> exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property.

Here is my `sonar-project.properties` file.

```
sonar.projectKey=XXX-XXX
sonar.projectName=XXX XXX
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=lib,pubspec.yaml
sonar.exclusions=**/*.java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.dart.analyzer.options.override=true
```

Here is how I am working, everything has already setup, and I write this command in my terminal which I get from my SonarQube dashboard

```
sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=XXX-XXX \
  -Dsonar.sources=. \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:9005 \
  -Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: that's weird, Sonar is used to scan Java files. Why do u exclude all of *.java files 

Comment: ah right, as I investigate a month ago, there's currently NO tool for analyze code for Flutter, except flutter_lints. Sonar is used to scan project like Android Java native, Java backend project... If you are FORCED to use Sonar by your boss, your cofigure should change this line: `sonar.sources=android/app`

Comment: I changed `sonar.sources=android/app` but still same issue.

Comment: did u try to remove `sonar.exclusions`?

Comment: yeah, still same error

Comment: Kindly check my updated question

Comment: how's it going bro?

Comment: still facing issue